# Fast Car implementation in python

Tags: python

I want to print numbers from 1 to 100, but for multiples of 3 I want to print "Fast" ,for multiples of 7 I want to print "Car" and for multiples of both 3 & 7 I want to print "Fast Car" instead of that number. Here I'm trying to implement it using Python. This is my 1st program in Python. Here I'm getting syntax error. Can any one help me with this??

```
  for num in range(1,100)
          if num%3==0 & num%7==0
            print "Fast Car"
          elif num%3==0
             print"Fast"
          elif num%7==0
        print "Car"
          else
        print num
```

Comment: I gave 1 tab space after 2nd elif statement(print statement)

Comment: Note: operator `&` does not mean the logical "and". Use operator `and` instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python FizzBuzz in one line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890037/python-fizzbuzz-in-one-line)

Comment: Rolled back to the original version. It doesn't make sense to correct the errors yielding to the question because then the question does not make sense any more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error log should give you some tips on the line where you get the error.

Yet, you forgot to use `:` at the end of your for statement and your if statements:

```
for num in range(1,100):
   if num%3==0 and num%7==0:
      print "Fast Car"
   elif num%3==0:
      print"Fast"
   elif num%7==0:
      print "Car"
   else:
      print num
```

Edit : and don't forget you need to indent correctly (this is the way Python works)

Edit 2: damn, Niclas raised that point before me :)

At last, if you've never written Python before, try to read and follow a tutorial, one of the best is surely [Dive into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/)

Edit 3 : have a look at Johnsyweb's answer for commented code and a link to the PEP 8 (Styling)

Comment: N.B: `&` does not mean the logical "and". Use operator `and` instead, as Howard said in the comments above.

Comment: @Johnsyweb: thanks. I've corrected my code

Answer (score 3):

You have to have colons in the end of each for, if, elif and else line. Also your identation are wrong...

Comment: Thanks Mr.Niclas. Now it's working. Here I've given 1 tab space after each if..elif..else. statements. How many space I need to give for correct identation.? Is there any specific rule for identation in Python??

Comment: No problem. There are no special rule on how many spaces you use (or if you use a tab) syntactically. But the good rule according to PEP-8 is to always ident eac block with 4 spaces. This is highly recommended.

Comment: Yes, I think my answer covers the recommended indentation.

Comment: I'm sure it does. But I just saw his question under my answer. Without looking further I just answered it. :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to work through [a Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) to get a grasp of Python, its syntax and indentation (whitespace is very important).

```
for num in range(1, 100): # For-statements end with a colon
    if num % 3 == 0 and num % 7 == 0: # Indentation is important 4 spaces per
                                      # block. 'and' is "logical and".
                                      # if-statements also end in a colon.
        print "Fast Car" # This line is indented 4 spaces from the 'if'
    elif num % 3 == 0:   # This lines up with 'if' and ends with a colon
        print "Fast"     # Indented 4 spaces from 'elif'
    elif num % 7 == 0:   # See previous 'elif'
        print "Car"      # See previous 'print'
    else:                # This lines up with 'if' and ends with a colon#
        print num        # See previous 'print'
```

I also recommend reading through [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Good luck! Python's a great language.

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to python as well but you can try starting with a colon ( : ) after your first line

```
for num in range(1,100):
```

you may even need it another place but I'm not sure.  I would try your code myself but I don't have the time right now

Comment: Mr.John.. Please check this out..                           http://py-ide-online.appspot.com/